# How to count using pydocumentdb?

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using pydocumentdb as sdk to access my CosmosDB(DocumentDB) database

I'm trying to execute this query

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c WHERE c._type="User"
```

And I'm getting different results each time I execute it using this `QueryDocuments` methods from `DocumentClient` class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by different results

Comment: @sajeetharan the count result is never the same integer value

Comment: It's very likely that this happens because the call runs out of resources and returns as soon at it can. Which version of pydocumentdb are you using?

Comment: @nick Version 1.7 but is there a way to do that?

Comment: 1.7 sounds quite old. You could use the query iterator returned an read each page of the results, and add them to a final result, but i don't have any experience with the python library. I will have a read through the docs.

Comment: @nick I know. It is an old version. I'll try your suggestion in mean while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i followed the tip given by @nick-chapsas i found the solution.
Here it is the result code

```
    from pydocumentdb import document_client

    DB_HOST = "my-host"
    DB_KEY = "my key=="
    DB_DATABASE = "my database"
    DB_COLLECTION = "my collection"

    dbclient = document_client.DocumentClient(DB_HOST, {'masterKey': DB_KEY})
    path = 'dbs/{}/colls/{}'.format(DB_DATABASE, DB_COLLECTION)


    query = "SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c JOIN chk0 IN c.communities WHERE chk0.id='bliive' AND c._type='User'"
    result = [dta for dta in dbclient.QueryDocuments(path, query)]

    print("count:")
    print(str(sum(result)))
```

Thank you!